# disable all form buttons in a given duration?

Tags: c#

I have a form in C# which has 4 buttons. I would like to disable all 4 buttons after a given duration of time, for example in 1 or 2 minutes. I searched in Google and found this code but it does not seem to work:

```
private System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60) { AutoReset = false };

protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60);
    aTimer.Interval = 60;
    double counter = aTimer.Interval;
    counter++;
    if (counter >= 60)
    {
        lib_bt.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Time Up!");
    }
```

Comment: The tick event will fire when the timer duration gets hit. there is no need to check the timer interval. simply just disable your buttons in there - that literally should be the only code there

Comment: @L.B Most likely WinForms, judging by the code. WPF Button doesn't have `.Enabled` property; it's `.IsEnabled`.  And the fact that's not using `DispatcherTimer`.  But then again, I don't think he fully understands the code he's using.

Comment: I would use Forms.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer so you don't have to invoke the button disable back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tick method will execute after the interval you define. Simply make sure you set `Button.Enabled` to false.

```
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);


private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    lib_bt.Enabled = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Time Up!");
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    button4.Enabled = false;
}
```

`button1` to `button4` should be replaced by the names of your buttons.

**Please note :**

- The interval is defined in ***milliseconds***. You code will execute every 60 milliseconds. For 1 minute, you should set the interval to *`60000`*
- The `aTimer` is defined twice. Why?

Answer (score 2):

60 seconds == 60000 milliseconds  .... fyi

Here's how it may look:

```
private static System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

public static void Main()
{
    myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);  // 60 seconds
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisableButtons); // subscribe
    myTimer.AutoReset = false; // if you don't want a reset
    myTimer.Enabled = true;    // enable it
}

// perform when event is fired off
private static void DisableButtons(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Enabled = false;
    button2.Enabled = false;
    button3.Enabled = false;
    button4.Enbaled = false;
}
```

Comment: @Ahmedilyas: You don't need to. As soon as you set the `Timer.Enabled` property to true, the code will execute after the defined period.

Comment: Right but in order to then disable buttons etc...an event gets fired...the tick event...which is what your code looks like now

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I'm not the one that wrote that comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to disable all 4 buttons after a given duration of time

I think the simplest way would be using async/await of C# 5.0

```
async void DisableButtons(int seconds)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000 * seconds);
    //Your code to disable Buttons
}
```

Just invoke this method somewhere in your code and It will disable the buttons after **n** seconds.